# How to authorize subset of resource in .Net Core AuthorizationHandler

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I have an implementation of `AuthorizationHandler` that takes a `List<Guid>` as its resource. I check each guid to see if the current user has access to this particular resource. My question is, what if I discover they can access some of the guids but not others? Is there some way to reflect this case back to the controller by modifying the following code, or do I need to separately authorize each of the guids in the list?

```
protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, MyRequirement requirement, List<Guid> resource)
    {
        Guid myId = Guid.Parse(context.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "SomeClaim").Value);
        var allAccessableGuids = GetTheGuids(myId);

        foreach(var id in resource)
        {
            if(allAccessableGuids.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == id) == null)
            {
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        }
        context.Succeed(requirement);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

The code will currently fail the whole list if one guid is found to be unauthorized.
Note that variable names and methods have been changed for simplicity.

Comment: Is it not possible to pass a single `Guid` instead of a `List<Guid>` ? -- it doesn't seem to make sense to check an array. Maybe you can try and explain what exactly you are trying to solve.

Comment: The reason I wanted to do this via a list is because the method GetTheGuids involves a heavy database call. I want to avoid at all costs repeating the same query within the same http request, so I thought if I could do it once and check them all it would be much more efficient.